# How to get the path of the application directory?

Tags: android, qml

I wants to save images downloaded from the Internet in a directory with the application but do not know how to appeal to the path from QML on android?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML

Comment: Is that the way you prefer an answer to your question too?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: In your post you forgot to tell what QML is. It would be nice if you did.

Comment: @greenapps: click on the tag to see what QML is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this in C++ as far as I'm aware.

To get the application directory, use [QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath):

```
qDebug() << QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
```

That will print out something like:

```
"/data/app-lib/org.example.stuff-1"
```

To save stuff, I think it's recommended to use [QStandardPaths](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html):

```
qDebug() << QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DataLocation);
```

That will print out something like:

```
QDir( "/data/data/org.example.stuff/files" , nameFilters = { * },  QDir::SortFlags( Name | IgnoreCase ) , QDir::Filters( Dirs|Files|Drives|AllEntries ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant.

Comment: Ok but do not forget to give voice to your post. Now I can not do this because I have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

I have needed to get path to libraries and I have solved it so:

```
QFileInfo(argv[0]).dir().absolutePath()
```

maybe you want the same.